DirectX distorted/stretched triangle render
I'm currently making a simple DirectX engine to brush up some of my graphics programming knowledge, but currently I've been frustratingly stuck for a while. I'm trying to render a simple triangle with a moving camera (only translation for now), but the triangle seems to distort whenever I move the camera. The same happens whenever I move the triangle, but then the distortion happens in the opposite direction ofcourse.
This is how the triangle looks without camera movement:

This is how it looks when I move the camera to the right:

And this is how it looks when I move the camera up:

My first thought was that the WorldViewProjection matrix was off somehow, but I don't really see any problem with it.
void Renderer::CreateViewProjectionMatrix()
{
    using namespace DirectX;

    // Create world matrix
    const XMMATRIX translation = XMMatrixTranslation(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    const XMMATRIX rotation = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);  // In radians
    const XMMATRIX scale = XMMatrixScaling(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);

    const XMMATRIX worldMatrix = scale * rotation * translation;
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_VertexConstantBuffer.worldMatrix, worldMatrix);

    // Create view matrix
    const XMFLOAT3 cameraForward{ 0.f, 0.f, 1.f };
    const XMFLOAT3 cameraUp{ 0.f, 1.f, 0.f };

    const XMVECTOR worldPos = XMLoadFloat3(&m_CameraPos);
    const XMVECTOR worldForward = XMLoadFloat3(&cameraForward);
    const XMVECTOR worldUp = XMLoadFloat3(&cameraUp);

    const XMMATRIX viewMatrix = XMMatrixLookToLH(worldPos, worldForward, worldUp);

    // Create projection matrix
    const float aspectRatioX = static_cast<float>(m_BackBufferDescription.Width) / m_BackBufferDescription.Height;
    const float FOV{ 45.f };
    const float nearZ{ 0.1f };
    const float farZ{ 100.f };
    const XMMATRIX projectionMatrix = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(XMConvertToRadians(FOV), aspectRatioX, nearZ, farZ);

    // Store WVP matrix
    const XMMATRIX WVPMatrix = worldMatrix * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix;
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_VertexConstantBuffer.worldViewProjection, WVPMatrix);
}

Here's how the triangle gets created in case you need it:
HRESULT Renderer::CreateTriangle()
{
    // Create triangle geometry
    const BaseVertexInput triangleVertices[] =
    {
        { DirectX::XMFLOAT3{ -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.0f }, DirectX::XMFLOAT3{}, DirectX::XMFLOAT2{} },
        { DirectX::XMFLOAT3{  0.5f,-0.5f, 0.0f }, DirectX::XMFLOAT3{}, DirectX::XMFLOAT2{} },
        { DirectX::XMFLOAT3{  0.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f }, DirectX::XMFLOAT3{}, DirectX::XMFLOAT2{} }
    };

    // Create vertexBuffer
    const CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexDescription{ sizeof(triangleVertices), D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER};

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexData;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));    // Stops writes being compiled away if it isn't being read immeadiatly
    vertexData.pSysMem = triangleVertices;                      // Initialization data
    vertexData.SysMemPitch = 0;                                 // Distance from beginning line of texture to the next line (only for 2D & 3D texture)
    vertexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;                            // Distance from beginning of one depth level to the next   (only for 3D texture)

    HRESULT result = m_pDevice->CreateBuffer
    (
        &vertexDescription,
        &vertexData,
        m_pVertexBuffer.GetAddressOf()
    );

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        Logger::Log(L"ERROR - Failed to create a vertexBuffer");
        return result;
    }

    // Create indexBuffer
    const unsigned short triangleIndices[]
    {
        0,2,1
    };

    m_IndexCount = ARRAYSIZE(triangleIndices);

    const CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC indexDescription{ sizeof(triangleIndices), D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER };

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA indexData;
    ZeroMemory(&indexData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
    indexData.pSysMem = triangleIndices;
    indexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    indexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    result = m_pDevice->CreateBuffer
    (
        &indexDescription,
        &indexData,
        m_pIndexBuffer.GetAddressOf()
    );

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        Logger::Log(L"ERROR - Failed to create an indexBuffer");
        return result;
    }

    // Creation success
    m_SuccesfullCreation = true;
    return result;
}

I looked into: the WVP matrix, my vertex shader, creation of vertex buffer, ...
I tried to do the Transpose(RightHandMatrix(...)) thingy from the Microsoft guide, but then I just don't see any triangle at all.
Besides that I don't really have any clue where to look anymore.
Definitely ask if there's more code I can/need to provide.
EDIT:
Here's my complete vertex shader as well:

cbuffer CB_World : register(b0)    // Register for GPU access (b. for constant buffers)
{
    matrix g_WorldViewProjection;   // World to projection space
    matrix g_World;                 // World space
};

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 position : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;  // System value
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

VS_OUTPUT VSMain(VS_INPUT input)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;
    
    output.position = mul(float4(input.position, 1.0), g_WorldViewProjection);
    output.normal = normalize(mul(input.normal, (float3x3) g_World));
    output.uv = input.uv;
    
    return output;
}

GitHub:
https://github.com/RenzoDepoortere/DistortedRender_AidProject

The C++ code looks ok but you'll need to post your vertex shader code, because this looks like a vertex transformation issue.

@MaicoDeBlasio I updated the post with the vertex shader code.

Would be better with a fully simple reproducing project. Devil hides in details

Vertex shader looks ok (except you shouldn't be normalizing the normal yet... you should do it in the pixel shader after interpolation by the rasterizer). Can't think what it may be except perhaps you might need to transpose your matrices before binding to cbuffers (although you mentioned you've already tried that).

@SimonMourier you want me to send the whole project? or just to start over?

@MaicoDeBlasio damn, thanks for trying eitherway. I'll try the transpose matrix again and otherwise I might try to redo the rendering parts.

You can post it somewhere on the internet (github, whatever)

@SimonMourier added a GitHub link to the post

Code in the question does not match code in the project. Here you use XMMatrixLookToLH while in project XMMatrixLookAtLH. For me result looks like it was produced by code using XMMatrixLookAtLH. Also please read about [mcve].

@user7860670 Sorry, you're right. There were some minor tweaks between posting the question and posting the GitHub link (basically just removing comments, changing variable names from "cube" to "triangle" and the "major" change is the XMMatrixLookAtLH/XMMatrixLookToLH function). I updated the code to more closely represent what I had at time of posting the question.
Also, for the minimal reproducible example, I'm not sure how much more I can shave off the project as there really just is the main function and the renderer + the inputManager for debug convenience.

Also also, changing XMMatrixLookAtLH with XMMatrixLookToLH reproduces the same result.

"changing XMMatrixLookAtLH with XMMatrixLookToLH reproduces the same result" - now this statement is difficult to believe. They treat second argument differently. Passing 0.f, 0.f, 1.f as second argument to XMMatrixLookToLH means that when moving camera position (passed as first argument) view direction will be kept parallel to z axis. While passing 0.f, 0.f, 1.f as second argument to XMMatrixLookAtLH means that when moving camera position (again passed as first argument) view direction will be changed to point at 0.f, 0.f, 1.f (camera will be rotated that is).

@user7860670 I didn't phrase it quite well. I meant that I received the same results using XMMatrixLookToLH  with cameraForward as second argument and XMMatrixLookAtLH with cameraPosition + cameraForward as second argument. I assumed you already looked at the project.

I've downloaded and built project, the problem seems to be a combination of two:

use of XMMatrixLookAtLH instead of XMMatrixLookToLH. They treat second argument differently. Passing 0.f, 0.f, 1.f as second argument to XMMatrixLookToLH means that when moving camera position (passed as first argument) view direction will be kept parallel to z axis. While passing 0.f, 0.f, 1.f as second argument to XMMatrixLookAtLH means that when moving camera position (again passed as first argument) view direction will be changed to point at 0.f, 0.f, 1.f (camera will be rotated that is).
Lack of transpose call at the end:

const XMMATRIX WVPMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(worldMatrix * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix);

Result with XMMatrixLookToLH after camera is moved to the right a bit:

Result with XMMatrixLookAtLH after camera is moved to the right a bit, which also causes it to ratate to keep looking at the same 0.f, 0.f, 1.f point:


Wow such a small thing I missed . But thanks a lot, I really appreciate it. I never would've guessed I needed a transpose right at the end.

@RenzoDP You should also read Why do we need to use the "transpose" of a transformed matrix?

Alright that makes sense, I should probably transpose my world matrix as well then. Thanks!
